# Custom cells with common features in ios

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview, custom-cell

I have an app in which I have a tableview. Inside this tableview I currently have 8 different types of cells. Each of these cells are different but also have similarities.

As an example (using only 2 cells for simplicity). Imagine you have cell 1 which can be divided into 3 parts:

--------------A--------------
--------------B--------------
--------------C--------------

Now cell 2 also has 3 parts. Parts A and C are the same as in cell1 (different data of course, but same structure):

--------------A--------------
--------------D--------------
--------------C--------------

Currently, in my cellForRowAt method I just check if the cell type should be 1 or 2 and then I dequeue cell for that type. The challenge is that I would like to avoid setting part A and C two different places in the code.

Eg. instead of

```
if type == type1 {
    //Set A
    //Set B
    //Set C
} else if type == type2 {
    //Set A
    //Set D
    //Set C
}
```

I would like

```
//Set A
//Set C
if type == type1 {
    //Set B
} else if type == type2 {
    //Set D
}
```

I was wondering if there is a way to "abstract" these commonalities?

Please let me know if anything is unclear.

**EDIT: IB Challenge**

I probably should also mention that a tricky part for me is figuring out how a parent cell would fit in in regards to IB. I have separate xib files for each cell type, but if I would only have one parent swift file with section A and C, can both my other xib files have the same outlets to this parent and how would this even be done?

Comment: Your two cell classes will need to inherit from a common superclass that defines both `A` and `C`, with the subclasses defining `B` and `D`.

Comment: Hi Paulw11, Yes that is the approach I'm trying to get to work. But please check my edit - which is actually my primary challenge to this I suppose.

Comment: You would need two nib files, one has custom class `type1` and the other with custom class `type2`. The outlets defined by the parent class are visible for both `type1` and `type2` so you can connect everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Parent TableViewCell`

```
class BaseTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

  @IBOutlet weak var ALabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var CLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

`Subclass of BaseCell`

```
class TypeOneTableViewCell: BaseTableViewCell {

  @IBOutlet weak var BLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi José,
This seems like exactly what I am looking for! Is it possible to have outlets connected to multiple Controllers? Not sure I am stating that correctly, but concretely in your example. Is it possible to connect ALabel and CLabel in BaseViewController to both TypeOneTableViewCell and TypeTwoTableViewCell? I will of course try this now, I am just wondering if there are any pitfalls doing this?

Comment: There aren't any PitFalls, This is the correct way of doing it.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure What do you mean by 'Multiple Controllers', in this example, We're talking about a Hierarchy of Views (TableViewCells), The same pattern can be used if you want to do the same with ViewControllers.

Comment: Hi José I am just testing it out. By the time I figure all the steps out I definitely will mark it as correct answer! By multiple controllers I just mean that there will be multiple "child" controllers inheriting BaseViewController. All of these child controllers needs their A and C part linked to A and C outlets in the BaseViewController as I understand it.

Comment: Yes. that's exactly right, you can have as many child viewcontrollers as you like inheriting from the parent viewcontroller, and they will only need to include the changing part (B or D), and how you connect the outlets you proceed as I instructed in the Images.